# How to disable the message "Do you want to get started with Microsoft Web Platform to stay connected with latest Web Platform Components?"

Tags: microsoft-web-platform

How do I disable the message (via registry/script)

> Do you want to get started with Microsoft Web Platform to stay
>   connected with latest Web Platform Components?

It seems like a trivial one click dismissal but I have cloud formation Windows 2012 R2 server builds in AWS which are spun up and killed off regularly.

It's driving me nuts when I log onto a fresh box and load the IIS panel. I tried `procmon` to see what changes when I click no-don't-bug-me-about-this-again but haven't managed to find the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done easily as the setting is stored in

> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\WebManagement\7.0.0.0\InetMgr.preferences

([source](https://forums.iis.net/p/1230529/2117821.aspx))

Luckily however, I am an AutoHotKey ninja and have this chocolatey package installed as part of my automation

```
choco install web-platform-disable-prompt
```

([more](https://chocolatey.org/packages/web-platform-disable-prompt/1.0.0.0))

Update: The chocolatey package only works inside a shell session - ie: RDP. It won't work over WinRM in Packer for example. A work around may be to inject it as a one time run in `StartMenu\Startup`